# "d" parameter returns undefined in a .on event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

I have a problem where the `d` parameter in D3.js returns `undefined`.
This is the code I have right now

```js
const buttons = d3.select("body")
  .data(countries)
  .enter()
  .append("button")
  .text((d) => { return d.location; })              // returns name location
  .attr("value", (d) => { return d.location; })     // returns name location
  .on("click", (d) => { console.log(d.location) }); // returns undefined
```

On the buttons I see the right text and the value of the location, so it is working properly there, but on my click event I want to change a variable with the name of the specific country, but it returns undefined.

Comment: Maybe you need to use a traditional function over the arrow-function? Because you can't bind `this`. See: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/event-handling-in-d3js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the "click" event gives you the `event` param first, then the `datum`:

> When a specified event is dispatched on a selected element, the specified listener will be evaluated for the element, being passed the current event (event) and the current datum (d), with this as the current DOM element (event.currentTarget). Listeners always see the latest datum for their element.

[Related docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#handling-events)

I think you're looking for this:

```js
const countries = [
  {
    location: 'USA',
  },
  {
    location: 'Canada',
  }
];

const buttons = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll('button')
  .data(countries)
  .enter()
  .append("button")
  .text((d) => { return d.location; })              // returns name location
  .attr("value", (d) => { return d.location; })     // returns name location
  .on("click", (e, d) => { console.log(d.location) }); // returns name location
```

[Related Codepen](https://codepen.io/joseph4tw/pen/Pozzxov?editors=1111)